# How to test network timeout exception on Windows Phone 8 Emulator

Tags: networking, testing, windows-phone-8, timeout

My user has reported me an issue of network timeout in my app.

I want to reproduce it on Windows Phone 8 Emulator hosted on Hyper-V.

But since my network is always connected, not like a mobile network, I always have the correct result. Seems to be no way to simlutate network timeout.

Does anyone know how to reproduce this kind of issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to [disable networking in the Hyper-V manager](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/10/01/why-can-t-the-windows-phone-emulator-go-online.aspx). Here is some example how to enable networking, but you can easily disable it in the same way.